удаляются ли указатели в локальных классах
Я знаю, что локальные переменные существуют только в своей локальной области видимости, после завершения цикла или тп. они уничтожаются, если это не указатель. Но если этим локальным объектом будет класс с указателем внутри, удалится ли этот указатель самостоятельно или мне нужно чистить всё вручную?
class A {
private:
    int* ptr;
public:
    A(int n) {
        ptr = new int[n];
    }
};

int main() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        A a(i);
    }
    return 0;
}


Указатель удалится, а вот память утечет. Если есть new, то должен быть и delete[], если не используются умные указатели.

То есть если я, например, присваиваю уже существующий указатель, например на массив, то утечек не будет?

Не очень понял вопрос без кода.

Указатель удалится; то, на что он указывает — нет. Все, что надо освободить, освобождайте самостоятельно в деструкторе.

Смешились в кучу люди, кони... В С++ объект удаляется только при явном вызове оператора delete. При выходе из области видимости объекта с автоматическим временем хранения этот объект разрушается, то бишь у него вызывается деструктор и освобождается занимаемая им память. Если тип объета - указатель, то будет формально произведен вызов его деструктора (который ничего не делает, как и у других примитивных типов) и освобождена память, занимаемая этим указателем. С объектом, на который тот указывал, ничего не происходит.

Вызов оператора new создает объект с динамическим временем хранения (читайте с ручным). Он будет разрушен при вызове оператора delete. С другой стороны, вызывать этот оператор вручную нет необходимости, для этого есть умные указатели и RAII.
